# Entity Framework Where() ignored with FromSqlRaw(FreeTextTable)

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

This is with Entity Framework Core 8. I have the following query:

```
var fullTextQuery = $"SELECT top {maxRows} * FROM FreeTextTable(Organizations, *, {{0}}, {maxRows}) as t INNER JOIN Organizations u on u.Id = t.[KEY]";

var query = dbContext.Organizations
    .FromSqlRaw(fullTextQuery, queryText);
    .Where(org => org.Name.Contains(itemName))
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is returning objects that the `FreeTextTable()` should return, but that the `Where()` clause should exclude. Is the `Where()` clause ignored? Or do I need to add it literally into the `FromRawSql()`? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, though there are limits, mainly around stored procedures. <s>That said you should be using `FromSql` not `FromSqlRaw` unless absolutely necessary.</s> (`FromSqlRaw` is needed here for parameterizing SQL statements.)

On a hunch I would consider restructuring the query a little:

```
var fullTextQuery = $"SELECT u.* FROM Organizations u INNER JOIN FreeTextTable(Organizations, *, {{0}}, {maxRows}) as t ON u.Id = t.[KEY]";

var query = await dbContext.Organizations
    .FromSqlRaw(fullTextQuery, queryText); 
    .Where(org => org.Name.Contains(itemName))
    .ToListAsync();
```

The "TOP(maxRows)" is covered by the inner join to the top results from the free text search. I would expect this may be enough to get it happy to allow the where clause if EF is satisfied that the query is going to the Organizations table initially.

Otherwise if the query does run but still does not seem to take into account the `Where` clause, run a profiler to capture the SQL actually used and this might shed some light on some funniness remaining in the query parsing.

Comment: Flipping the order of the tables in the query did it. But I retained `FromSqlRaw()` because the documentation said `FromSql()` doesn't handle parametrizing the variables and does not have an option to pass in variables (that I could find)???

Comment: Hmm, yes `FromSql` supports parameters, but it appears to be limited to stored proc calls. Parameterizing an SQL statement requires `FromSqlRaw`.